# Java reflecting nested anonymous classes

Tags: java, reflection

Why does this code return "class java.lang.Object" ?

```
Object a = new Object() {
  public Object b = new Object(){
    public int c;
  };
};

System.out.println(a.getClass().getField("b").getType());
```

Why does the inner-inner type get lost? How can I reflect the c field ?

Edit:

This one works (as pointed out in some answers):

```
a.getClass().getField("b").get(a) ...
```

But then I have to invoke a getter, is there any way to reflect c with only reflection meta data?

Comment: the inner type **IS** Object. It's anonymous extending Object!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `b` is declared as `Object`:

```
public Object b = ...;
```

There is a distinction between type of variable (static type) and type of the object referenced by that variable (runtime type).

`Field.getType()` returns static type of the field.

If you want to get runtime type of the object referenced by the field, you need to access that object and call `getClass()` on it (since `a` is declared as `Object` and therefore `b` is not visible as its member you have to use reflection to access it):

```
System.out.println(
     a.getClass().getField("b").get(a).getClass());
```

**UPDATE:** You can't reflect `c` without accessing the instance of object containing it. That's why these types are called anonymous - a type containing `c` has no name, so that you can't declare field `b` as a field of that type.

Comment: So is 'a' and it isn't of type java.lang.Object

Comment: "a.b" isn't legal because the b field doesn't exists in type java.lang.Object

Comment: You cannot access b this way because a is just a plain Object for the compiler. You'll get an error like "b cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at this line carefully:

```
System.out.println(a.getClass().getField("b").getType());
```

First, your take the `a` variable. It is of some anonymous subclass of the Object. Let's call that class `MyClass$1`. Okay, so far so good.

Next, you call the getClass() method. It returns the class of a, that is, a description of the `MyClass$1` class. This description is not tied to any particular instance of that class, though. The class is the same for all instances, be it `a` or whatever else (unless different class loaders are used). In this particular case, however, there can be only one instance, because the class is anonymous, but the mechanism is still the same.

Now, from the class, you get the field `b`. As the class isn't directly tied to any of this instances, the field has nothing to do with `a` either. It's just a description of what exactly the field `a` of the class `MyClass$1` is.

Now you get its type. But since it isn't tied to any instance, it can't know the runtime type. In fact, if the class wasn't anonymous, you could have numerous instances of `MyClass$1`, each having different value in `a`. Or you could have no instances at all. So the only thing getType() can possibly tell you is the declared type of `b`, which exactly what it does. The `b` field could in fact be `null` at that point, and you'd still get `Object` as the result.

The Field class provides the get() method to actually access that particular field of some object, like this:

```
System.out.println(a.getClass().getField("b").get(a).getClass());
```

Now you get something like `MyClass$1$1`, which is the name of the anonymous class of the object that field `b` references to, *in the `a` instance*.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the inner-inner type get lost?

Because you are getting the type type of the field "b" (Object), not the type of the anonymous inner class of which you assigned the instance to "b".

> How can I reflect the c field ?

You could use this

```
System.out.println(a.getClass().getField("b").get(a).getClass().getField("c"));
```

instead. This gets the value of the field "b" and it's class, but this only works if "b" is guaranteed be not null.

Doing this seems to indicate a bad design, there might be other ways to archive what you want to do with this. But without knowing the purpose, this is everything I can answer.

Comment: Well I don't have any actual purpose with this code, I just stumbled upon it and wanted to know why it behaves like it behaves. So there aren't  any ways to reflect c with only meta data (ie. without using get(a)) ?

Comment: OK, curiosity is always fine :) As far as I know there is no way with anonymous inner classes because you don't have a way to get those classes java.lang.Class-instance without having an actual instance of the anonymous class (except for Class.forName() etc. obviously)